# Heat Equation with source and convection

Tags: calculus

consider a spherical object heated in a microwave oven, the process can be modelled with a heat source q(x,t) =Qoe^(k(r-a)) where k is a constant and a is the radius of the sphere, (r is distance from the centre of the sphere)

modelling heat transfer to the air at the surface of the sphere by flux J.n =h(U-Uo) where U is the temperature in the sphere and Uo is the temperature of the air around the sphere.

ignoring heat conduction , find the time required to heat the sphere to temperature U1 throughout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of open-ended parameters in the above problem statement, so we will have to use a tool like guessing to determine their values. Let's assume that $q(x,t)$ means heat generated per unit volume per unit time, and $\vec J\cdot\hat n$ means heat flux out of the sphere per unit area per unit time, ignoring heat conduction means that thermal conductivity is high enough that the sphere remains at uniform temperature, the initial temperature is $U_0$, the specific heat capacity per unit mass is $C_p$ and the density is $\rho$. Then the rate of heat generation in the sphere is
$$\begin{align}Q_{gen}&=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\sin\theta\int_0^ar^2Q_0e^{k(r-a)}dr\,d\theta\,d\phi\\
&=4\pi Q_0e^{-ka}\left.\left(\frac{r^2}k-\frac{2r}{k^2}+\frac2{k^3}\right)e^{kr}\right|_0^a\\
&=4\pi a^3Q_0\left(\frac1{ka}-\frac2{(ka)^2}+\frac2{(ka)^3}\left(1-e^{-ka}\right)\right)\end{align}$$
The rate of heat loss at the surface is
$$Q_{conv}=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\sin\theta\,a^2h(U-U_0)d\theta\,d\phi=4\pi a^2h(U-U_0)$$
So we can get the rate of change of temperature
$$\begin{align}\frac{dU}{dt}&=\frac{Q_{gen}-Q_{conv}}{mC_p}=\frac{4\pi a^3Q_0\left(\frac1{ka}-\frac2{(ka)^2}+\frac2{(ka)^3}\left(1-e^{-ka}\right)\right)-4\pi a^2h(U-U_0)}{\frac43\pi a^3\rho C_p}\\
&=-AU+B\end{align}$$
Where of course
$$A=\frac{3h}{a\rho C_p}$$
And
$$B=\frac{3aQ_0\left(\frac1{ka}-\frac2{(ka)^2}+\frac2{(ka)^3}\left(1-e^{-ka}\right)\right)+3hU_0}{a\rho C_p}$$
The general solution to the differential equation is
$$U=\frac BA+ce^{-At}$$
Applying the assumed initial condition
$$U(0)=U_0=\frac BA+c$$
We get
$$U(t)=\frac BA+\left(U_0-\frac BA\right)e^{-At}=U_1$$
When our spherical cow has reached the right yummy temperature. We can solve to get
$$t=\frac1A\ln\left(\frac{U_0-\frac BA}{U_1-\frac BA}\right)$$